# Animated time series flow chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram, flow-diagram

My apologies as I am new to this, but I have done a lot of searching and I can't seem to find an open source example of what I am looking for.

I want to visualize the flow of people through a system in the style of a flow chart.

However, I would like to be able to have the boxes of the flow chart, representing each stage, change size (including appearing and disappearing) depending on the number of people at that stage, at a certain time.

I have seen animated Sankey diagrams using d3 where the path size changes over time, but I am trying to mirror a static flow diagram we publish and this looks too different.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so could anyone point me in the direction of a suitable example?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a custom thing so I don't think an example exists -- you're also quite vague about what you want. In any case, the Sankey plugin is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's quite possible. You have to collect the date through your system and transform those data compatible with Shankey so that Shankey can understand it. You have to refresh the data to Sankey after a certain period of time to reflect the latest update. I have a feeling that you also need to optimize this process for the performance shake.